# Connect three kitchen appliances to same water line?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, sink, dishwasher, plumbing-fixture

In the kitchen, I'm trying to connect the sink, dishwasher, and washing machine to the same hot water line.

Currently, my hot water has dishwasher and sink are hooked up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7mra.jpg

I use this water tee stop, can I connect two of them together to allow three connections? https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJSLA.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can connect multiple things by stacking tee fittings.

There are two things to be aware of with the specific arrangement you're considering. One is that 3/8" hose is terribly small for a [clothes] washing machine. You'll do better to remove the angle stop valve, which sits on 1/2" pipe, and insert a tee there with a 1/2" valve just to serve the clothes washer.

The other thing to be aware of is that if more than one thing demands hot water at the same time the flow to all the things will be low. The 1/2" supply pipe is just too small to serve concurrent loads. If you can deal with the reduced flow, or simply coordinate the uses to avoid concurrency, it'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you! So just to be sure, to the 1/2" supply pipe, I can insert a tee with two 1/2" outputs, then move the angle stop valve to one output, and the washing machine to the other?

Comment: @MichaelCheng Yes, I that's the best that can be done in this situation.